# Final render with baked data? (ocean)

Tags: rendering

I'm following this tutorial, and at the final stage (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n8PSS5HqC-Q&t=1353s&ab_channel=DylanNeill)

I baked the ocean modifiers (including foam), and put the image sequences into shader for an object as such:
[image]

I'm trying to make a render of an animation with the ocean moving, but the tutorial assumes you know already, which I don't.

How do you do this?

Comment: Hello, so you don't know what exactly? How to make a render? Go into Render > Render Animation (before that you need to choose the destination folder in the Output panel)

Comment: @moonboots, there is no extra stuff you gotta do? I assumed because it is baked data and put into Shading node, that it will not animate. It didn't animate when I hit the play button in Render mode.